# What simple arguments and insights can I observe that running both BFS and DFS can be achieved in O(|V| + |E|)?

Tags: graphs, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, graph-traversal

BFS and DFS can be achieved in O(|V| + |E|). I understand the proof but it seems a bit lengthy.

- Can I argue O(|V| + |E|) in a very simply way? e.g. checking each edge at most once?
- Also what does O(|V| + |E|) imply?

I know Dijstrka algorithm and many other algorithm is somewhat like BFS. Does it imply automatically they can be run in |V| + |E| is the [lower bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818079/why-use-dijkstras-algorithm-if-breadth-first-search-bfs-can-do-the-same-thing)?

Comment: "I understand the proof but it seems a bit lengthy." -- they aren't. I recommend you spend some time to understand these proofs. Otherwise you'll be completely lost when you enter more complex things.

Comment: "checking each edge at most once? " -- that's a central part of the proof.

Comment: "Also what does O(|V| + |E|) imply?" -- unfold the definition; what more are you looking for?

Comment: "I know Dijstrka algorithm and many other algorithm is somewhat like BFS." -- define "somewhat like". Yes, every algorithm that considers each part of the input has input size as a lower bound on the running time.

Comment: In total, I'm not sure there really is much of a question here. Community votes, please!

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, what a time upper bound of $O(|V| + |E|)$ means is that you spend $O(1)$ time per each vertex and each edge. Taking as an example DFS, there is one recursive call per edge, and the procedure itself runs once per vertex. You can turn this into a full-fledged argument that proves the upper bound.

An upper bound of $O(|V| + |E|)$ is optimal for most graph problems – those that potentially require examining all vertices and all edges. What such an upper bound tells you is that your problem can be solved in the minimal possible time; an $O(|V| + |E|)$ algorithm is an asymptotically optimal algorithm.